# Primeflex 3 and angular 12 unable to render

Tags: primeng, primeflex

[image: in my browser] In my browser

[image: in priflex doc] In  primeflex doc

And yes i've already installed with the new stack, Angular 12 and Prime flex 3

```
<div class="card">
    <h5>Vertical and Grid</h5>
    <div class="formgrid grid">
        <div class="field col">
            <label for="firstname2">Firstname</label>
            <input id="firstname2" type="text" class="inputfield w-full">
        </div>
        <div class="field col">
            <label for="lastname2">Lastname</label>
            <input id="lastname2" type="text" class="inputfield w-full">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

anyone have the same problem ?

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I copied in the main.scss file, but that's not ideal for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I noticed that class card is given in the primeflex portal which is part of main.scss written by https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex and when we use primeflex in our application and if we see in primeflex.css, it does not have card class but, grid is there in primeflex.css